# How to designate unreachable python code

Tags: python

What's the pythonic way to designate unreachable code in python as in:

```
gender = readFromDB(...) # either 'm' or 'f'
if gender == 'm':
    greeting = 'Mr.'
elif gender == 'f':
    greeting = 'Ms.'
else:
    # What should this line say?
```

Comment: I don't think unreachable code is the correct term for this. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreachable_code

Comment: @unknown What would you suggest instead? I know this example is not that good, as the else loop is de-facto reachable. But as it happens, that's exactly the "measure of reachability" I'm looking for.

Comment: I'd call this "unexpected data values in an if/else statement" rather than "unreachable code".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
raise ValueError('invalid gender %r' % gender)
```

Comment: From the pythonic manifesto...

"...Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced."

Answer (score 9):

You could raise an exception:

```
raise ValueError("Unexpected gender; expected 'm' or 'f', got %s" % gender)
```

or use an assert False if you expect the database to return only 'm' or 'f':

```
assert False, "Unexpected gender; expected 'm' or 'f', got %s" % gender
```

Answer (score 8):

With python version 3.11+, you can use [`typing.assert_never`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.assert_never) to assert unreachability in a way that can be verified by static type checkers such as `mypy` and `pyright`.

```py
from typing import assert_never

foo: int = 123

if isinstance(foo, str):
    assert_never(foo)  # unreachable
```

Static type checkers will verify that the `if`-block above is indeed unreachable. If the `assert_never` block is reached at runtime, it will throw an `AssertionError`:

```py
>>> from typing import assert_never
>>> assert_never(123)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/.../lib/python3.11/typing.py", line 2464, in assert_never
    raise AssertionError(f"Expected code to be unreachable, but got: {value}")
AssertionError: Expected code to be unreachable, but got: 123
```

With pre-3.11 versions of python, you'll need to import `assert_never` from the [`typing_extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) module.

```py
from typing_extensions import assert_never  # python < 3.11
```

## Examples

### `assert_never` with `typing.Literal`

Here's an example using `typing.assert_never` together with [`typing.Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) to assert that the `else`-block from OP's question is unreachable:

```py
from typing import Literal
from typing_extensions import assert_never

var: Literal["m", "f"] = "m"

if var == "m":
    ...
elif var == "f":
    ...
else:
    assert_never(var)  # unreachable
```

### `assert_never` with `typing.NoReturn`

Here is an example with a function whose return-type annotation is [`typing.NoReturn`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NoReturn):

```py
import time
from typing import NoReturn
from typing_extensions import Never, assert_never

def foo() -> NoReturn:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

bar: Never = foo()

assert_never(bar)  # unreachable
```

The [`typing.Never`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Never) type is available in `typing` module for python >=3.11 and in `typing_extensions` for earlier versions of python.

### `assert_never` with `typing.Union`

Here's another example using `if`/`elif`/`else` blocks to match against the type of a variable:

```py
from typing import Union
from typing_extensions import assert_never

var: Union[int, str, float] = "123"

if isinstance(var, int):
    ...
elif isinstance(var, str):
    ...
elif isinstance(var, float):
    ...
else:
    assert_never(var)  # unreachable
```

For more examples, including matching against the values of an enum type, see the Python typing docs on [Unreachable Code and Exhaustiveness Checking](https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/unreachable.html).

Answer (score 7):

This depends on how sure you are of the gender being either `'m'` or `'f'`.

If you're absolutely certain, use `if...else` instead of `if...elif...else`. Just makes it easier for everyone.

If there's any chance of malformed data, however, you should probably raise an exception to make testing and bug-fixing easier. You *could* use a gender-neutral greeting in this case, but for anything bigger, special values just make bugs harder to find.

Comment: /Which/ exception type would you suggest? And everyone seems to get caught up in the example ;).

Comment: Probably `ValueError` as suggested by others. It seems to make the most sense: http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html

Comment: There is *always* a chance for malformed data.

Answer (score 7):

I actually think that there's a place for this.

```
class SeriousDesignError(Exception):
    pass
```

So you can do this

```
if number % 2 == 0:
    result = "Even"
elif number % 2 == 1:
    result = "Odd"
else:
    raise SeriousDesignError()
```

I think this is the most meaningful error message.  This kind of thing can only arise through design errors (or bad maintenance, which is the same thing.)

Comment: I would still include a descriptive string when raising SDE, like `raise SeriousDesignError('Numbers must be either even or odd')`

Comment: `AssertionError` already exists and is commonly used to, in a sense, protect the developer from himself.

Answer (score 4):

I sometimes do:

```
if gender == 'm':
    greeting = 'Mr.'
else:
    assert gender == 'f'
    greeting = 'Ms.'
```

I think this does a good job of telling a reader of the code that there are only (in this case) two possibilities, and what they are.  Although you could make a case for raising a more descriptive error than AssertionError.

Answer (score 4):

It depends exactly what you want the error to signal, but I would use a dictionary in this case:

```
greetings = {'m': 'Mr.', 'f': 'Ms.'}
gender = readFromDB(...)  # either 'm' or 'f'
greeting = greetings[gender]
```

If gender is neither m nor f, this will raise a KeyError containing the unexpected value:

```
greetings = {'m': 'Mr.', 'f': 'Ms.'}

>>> greetings['W']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    greetings['W']
KeyError: 'W'
```

If you want more detail in the message, you can catch & reraise it:

```
try:
    greeting = greetings[gender]
except KeyError,e:
    raise ValueError('Unrecognized gender %s' % gender)
```

Answer (score 3):

Until now, I've usually used a variation on John Fouhy's answer -- but this is not exactly correct, as Ethan points out:

```
assert gender in ('m', 'f')
if gender == 'm':
    greeting = 'Mr.'
else:
    greeting = 'Ms.'
```

The main problem with using an assert is that if anyone runs your code with the -O or -OO flags, the asserts get optimized away.  As Ethan points out below, that means you now have no data checks at all.  Asserts are a development aid and shouldn't be used for production logic.  I'm going to get into the habit of using a check() function instead -- this allows for clean calling syntax like an assert:

```
def check(condition, msg=None):
    if not condition:
        raise ValueError(msg or '')

check(gender in ('m', 'f'))
if gender == 'm':
    greeting = 'Mr.'
else:
    greeting = 'Ms.'
```

Going back to the original question, I'd claim that using an assert() or check() prior to the if/else logic is easier to read, safer, and more explicit:

- it tests the data quality first before starting to act on it -- this might be important if there are operators other than '==' in the if/else chain
- it separates the assertion test from the branching logic, rather than interleaving them -- this makes reading and refactoring easier

Comment: If you want to pre-verify you should do it with `if gender not in ('m','f'): raise SomeException` as `assert`s can be optimized out and then you have no verification at all.

Comment: Arg.  That's right.  I never use -O or -OO so I don't worry about it for my own code, but I agree it's a bad habit.  I'll fix the answer.